# How to reduce memory when predicting with tensorflow model in a loop

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-serving

I'm using an object detection model from [tensorflow](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/collections/object_detection/2) hub to iterate over an image dataset
and it keeps using more and more memory.
I've tried all possible things (that I know) but it's still the same result always.

```
#it's the same for all models, I ended up with this one because it's smallest
detector = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/2")


for i in range(num_images)
    img = read_img(img_paths[i])
    out = detector(img)
    del out, img 
    gc.collect() #garbage collector
    K.clear_session() #K keras backend
```

The images are fairly small, but after about 4-5k of them I hit the 16GB memory ceiling.

Unfortunately none of the models support batching.

Thank you for any help or ideas you can provide!

Comment: Did you try to redeuce the input size of images?

Comment: @abdou_dev yes, the issue I think is that the graph saves all the outputs continously.  I am surprised myself that it gets to grow this large

Comment: To get more performance when training model , you may reduce the input size of the image and adjust the batch size .

Comment: @abdou_dev thanks, as mentioned there is no batch size, if I were able to use batching this would be solved.

Comment: And why you can't?

Comment: @abdou_dev if you follow the link and check the models out you'll find that none of them support it as I mentioned in my question. I've tried despite that and it really doesn't work as it says in the documentation.

Comment: Are you using transfer learning?